# joining results in having clause from 2 different condtition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two variables in part of my having clause.  I can't use a if then because I need both results together.

```
having 
 qty>=0-- AND X.Dt=@IssueDate2   --TO RETURN 11-9 SC
 AND X.Dt=@IssueDate3_mjssun   --TO RETURN 11-2 HD
```

How can I write this to get both results I need. I want to to avoid a JOIN on the whole statements. Open to any toher ideas you may have.

Thanks!

Rudy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `@IssueDate2` or `@IssueDate3_mjssun` will not be null then

try like this:

```
having 
 qty>=0 
 AND ( X.Dt=@IssueDate2   OR  X.Dt=@IssueDate3_mjssun )
```